# How to group complicated condition in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to group by `region` where there are `customers`who has `type=a`

```
region customer type score
A       a        a     1
A       b        b     2
A       c        a     3 
B       d        c     4 
B       e        d     5 
C       f        a     6 
C       g        c     7
```

Therefore after first step

```
region customer type score
A       a        a     1
A       b        b     2
A       c        a     3 
C       f        a     6 
C       g        c     7
```

And then I groupby in `region`

```
region  sum(score)
A         6
C        13
```

also I'd like to extract customer whose `type=a`

```
region customer type
A         a      a
A         c      a 
C         f      a
```

Then I'd like to merge above.

My desired result is like following

```
customer sum_in_region
a           6
c           6
f          13
```

Are there any way to achieve this?

My work is till the second step..
How can I proceed further?

```
SELECT t1.region,t1.customer, t1.type, t1.score
  FROM yourTable t1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t2.region = t1.region
                  AND t2.type = 'a');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table to a derived table that does your first two steps.

```
SELECT t3.customer,
       x1.score
       FROM yourtable t3
            INNER JOIN (SELECT t1.region,
                               sum(score) score
                               FROM yourtable t1
                                    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                         FROM yourtable t2
                                                         WHERE t2.region = t1.region
                                                               AND t2.type = 'a')
                               GROUP BY t1.region) x1
                       ON x1.region = t3.region
       WHERE t2.type = 'a';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the windows functions to get your result; the first step filters for only rows where type is `a`, based on the region. The second step then gets the sum of scores, based again on the region, before selecting only customer and sum columns :

```
with filter_type_a as 
(select region, customer, type, score 
from
(select *,
sum(type=="a") over (partition by region) as counter
from your_table)
where counter > 0)

select customer, sum_region
from
(select customer, type,
sum(score) over (partition by region) as sum_region
from filter_type_a)
where type=="a";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4ffd43/14)

```
with country_tmp as
(SELECT t1.region,t1.customer, t1.type, t1.score
  FROM country t1
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM country t2
                WHERE t2.region = t1.region
                  AND t2.type = 'a'))
                  select y.customer, x.score from
(select a.region, sum(a.score) score from (
SELECT t1.region,t1.customer, t1.type, t1.score
  FROM country_tmp t1) a
group by region) x , (SELECT t1.region,t1.customer, t1.type
  FROM country_tmp t1
 Where t1.type = 'a') y where x.region = y.region;
```